# What is a Refreshing Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Refreshing Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| REFRESHING WORD™ | UNREFRESHING WORD™ |
| --- | --- |
| Hungrier | Hungriest |
| Refreshing | Reforming |
| Noon | Undeniable |
| Unsung | Poop |
| Deadly | Deathly |
| Barbie | Nincompoop |

And here is a CSV version:

```
REFRESHING WORD™, UNREFRESHING WORD™
Hungrier, Hungriest
Refreshing, Reforming
Noon, Undeniable
Unsung, Poop
Deadly, Deathly
Barbie, Nincompoop
```

Before you ask, it's not the fact that all the Refreshing Words™ have a pair of letters that are 2 characters apart; that was just there to throw you off. Think inside the box.

Comment: Just add all of your examples now. Don't try to make your puzzles interactive.

Comment: Is there something about superlatives?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was wrong. The Unrefreshing Words had counterexamples.

Comment: (Also, I highly recommend adding more examples. These puzzles only work because there's typically a lot of very different data to work with.)

Comment: I added a picture. Felt it should have one like the rest

Comment: @Peanut Could you add some more examples?

Comment: You should add all the examples.

Comment: Why is this question so hated that it receives the most downvotes ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An Unrefreshing Word

> Is one that contains, potentially anagrammed, a verb describing an action pertaining to bodily fluids

Examples:

> Hungriest -> Shit, Reforming -> Gore, Undeniable->Bleed, Poop->Poop, Deathly->Eat, Nincompoop->Poop

A Refreshing Word, is then any word that is not Unrefeshing

A big thank you to Maria Deleva in the chat, coming up with Hungriest and Undeniable.

Comment: Ewwww. I hope this is wrong.

Comment: @Peanut [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32317921#32317921)